# Pushwoosh native push message handling

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

I'm using PushWoosh services for handling push notifications on my PhoneGap based app.

But i have a problem with handling native push messages.

If i send the push notification over PushWoosh API or Management Panel it comes to device like this:

```
{"title":"test message","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","from":"400481817113","onStart":false,"foreground":true,"p":"["}
```

But if i send the push notification via Google Native Push Services with this payload:

```
{"title":"test title"}
```

It comes to device as:

```
{"message":"{\"title\":\"test title\"}","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","from":"400481817113","onStart":false,"foreground":true}
```

So this cause the title not shown on the notification ğanel if i send the push message over Google Services.

Here's my question: How can resolve this? What is the best way to show title on notification panel with sending message via Google?

> Edit:
>
> **I found the problem on myself :) My code was using json_encode as twice to encode the message. I remove one of them and the problem was
>   resolved.**